# Show alert everytime user failed to login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactstrap

I have alert component using [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/alerts/), but It only appears when user failed for the first time, the next time user failed to login, the alert doesn't show anymore.

How can I show the alert everytimes user failed to login?

here's my code

```
const Login = ({ alert, user}) => {
    const [ visible, setVisible ] = useState(false)
    
// alert variable is a null for the first time, and string when user failed to login


    const onDismiss = () => setVisible(!visible)

    return (
        <>
      {alert ? (
        <Alert
          style={{ position: "fixed", top: 0, width: "100vw", margin: 0 }}
          color="info"
          isOpen={visible}
          toggle={onDismiss}
        >
          {alert}
        </Alert>
      ) : null}
          // Rest of the code
        </>
    );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try If login Failed set `setVisible(true)`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the value of **alert** and **visible** is true in second time too.

Comment: This answer should be a comment!